# Add suffix to file with context menu in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, rename, batch-rename

Want to add a suffix to (rename) filenames via right click menu.

Like this:

1. Right click on file.
2. Select the suffix from context menu.
3. The file gets renamed.

I tried adding the following registry entry:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
  *
    shell
      old
        command
          cmd /c ren "%1" "%1 old"
```

But it results in syntax error.

Would be awesome if it could be used to select and rename multiple files at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
==> ren /?
Renames a file or files.

RENAME [drive:][path]filename1 filename2.
REN [drive:][path]filename1 filename2.
```

> Note that you cannot specify a new drive or path for your destination
>   file.

```
==> reg query "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Old\command"

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Old\command
    (Default)    REG_SZ    cmd /C for %%# in ("%1") do  ren "%~f#" "%~n# old%~x#"
```

Above registry setting leads to e.g. `ren "D:\tmp\dummy foo.txt" "dummy foo old.txt"`.

And yes, it could be used to select multiple files at once. Invokes a distinct `cmd` instance for every selected file.

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (helpful particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~#`, `%~f#`, `%~n#` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)