# add suffix (rename) to selected files

Tags: windows, command-line, shell

I found a script below for my problem adding suffix to selected files
but I don't know how to integrate it in the registry, have no experience in scripting

```
reg query "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Old\command"

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Old\command

    (Default)    REG_SZ    cmd /C for %%# in ("%1") do  ren "%~f#" "%~n# old%~x#"
```

Above registry setting leads to e.g. ren "D:\tmp\dummy foo.txt" "dummy foo old.txt".

And yes, it could be used to select multiple files at once. Invokes a distinct cmd instance for every selected file.

---

its suppose to just right click a file and click the script to run it
i would like to add a suffix word "DATA" to all selected files
im guessing ill just replace the word "old" to "DATA" in the script

Comment: Please think about improving the format and adding a more specific Windows tag. In addition it's not clear what's really our issue. There isn't a single question mark or anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really clear what your problem is. It seems to be you're unable to add it to the context menu and you don't know how the script works?

For the context menu bit just check on of the tutorials available for it, e.g. [this one from HowToGeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/). Run `regedit` instead of `reg` to get a nice visual interface or put the following text in a file that has a `.reg` extension and double click the file after saving it.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\old\command]
@="cmd /C for %%# in (\"%1\") do  ren \"%~f#\" \"%~n# DATA%~x#\""
```

As for your question about the script and how to replace the old with DATA: Yes.

Comment: it's from this post http://superuser.com/questions/980710/add-suffix-to-file-with-context-menu-in-windows-explorer

Comment: Good to link it but what IS your actual question with this Question? The Question you referenced contains a fully working example (for Windows 7) and I edit my answer to include some more information. But it's still not clear what your actual question is.

Comment: thanks, used notepad to save it as a reg file then double clicked to integrate it in the registry, can now add suffix to selected files in windows explorer